# How to get Unique ID for SharePoint Web-part?

Tags: web-part

I need to save some web-part specific data to database.

how can i get unique ID for specific web part?
I need something that will be static even if server will be stopped and running again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [GUID Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241442%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and add a uniq GUID to your web part. It will never change unless you do the change!